# Bitwise NOT of Java BigInteger is Negative

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, biginteger

I am trying to perform a bitwise not on a 128 bit BigInteger in Java. I have a 128 bit number which has the first 64 bits set to 1 and the last 64 bits set to 0 (I am playing with IPv6 masks).

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(2).pow(64).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftLeft(64);
System.out.println(b.toString(2));
```

This results in the following, if I output it using base 2:

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I am trying to flip/reverse all the bits using a bitwise not.

```
System.out.println(b.not().toString(2));
```

From my understanding of a bitwise not, I was expecting all the 1's to change to 0's and all the 0's to change to 1's, but I get the following instead:

-11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This also seems to match the documentation of the `not()` function:

> This method returns a negative value if and only if this BigInteger is non-negative

Is it a case of looping through all 128 bits and performing a bitwise not on each separate bit instead?

**UPDATE**
It probably helps if I try and explain what I was trying to achieve to give some context. I am manipulating IPv6 addresses and was trying to determine if a given IPv6 address was within a subnet or not based on an IPv6 mask.

Based on the responses, I think the following should work:

E.g.
Is 2001:db8:0:0:8:800:200c:417b within 2001:db8::/64?

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, InetAddress.getByName("2001:db8::").getAddress());
BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(64).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftLeft(64);

// First Address in Subnet
BigInteger first = n.and(b);

// Last Address in Subnet (this is where I was having a problem as it was returning a negative number)
BigInteger MASK_128 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(128).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
BigInteger last = first.add(b.xor(MASK_128));

// Convert our test IP into BigInteger
BigInteger ip = new BigInteger(1, InetAddress.getByName("2001:db8:0:0:8:800:200c:417b").getAddress());

// Check if IP is >= first and <= last
if ((first.compareTo(ip) <= 0) && (last.compareTo(ip) >= 0)) {
  // in subnet
}
```

Comment: My guess is something is going on with the sign bit.

Comment: Java is two's-complement. You *did* get the bits flipped, and then it printed out a signed binary number.

Comment: Is it possible to treat it as an unsigned number?

Comment: @chrixm unrelated, but why a `BigInteger` and not a `BitSet`?

Comment: Note that for all values, `x.not()` equals `x.negate().subtract(BigInteger.ONE)` (try it). I guess that explains the result you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it's the sign bit that is giving you the result that you don't want.

There are a couple of ways that you can get the inverted bits.  For both of them you will need a 128 bit mask value:

```
private static final BigInteger MASK_128 =
    BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(128).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
```

Then you can either mask the sign bit:

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(64).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftLeft(64);
System.out.println(MASK_128.andNot(b).toString(2));
```

Or invert directly using xor:

```
System.out.println(b.xor(MASK_128).toString(2));
```

I expect the mask value will be useful elsewhere once you start fleshing things out also.

Comment: Marking this the answer as I was able to use the code provided above to fix my issue.

Comment: Instead of `valueOf(2).pow(128)`, which is quite expensive, I'd rather use `.BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(128)`, which gives the same result but is a lot faster.

Comment: Hi @RudyVelthuis, your suggestion is clearer for sure.

Answer (score 1):

signed byte 64  = 01000000

Invert it

and we get signed byte -65 = 10111111

Sign "minus" is the "not" operator itself:

-1000000 = 0111111

Type this and you see that the values are equal (+1) in absolute

```
System.out.println(b.toString());
System.out.println(b.not().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is perfectly correct ,In java everything is in two's compliment:

**Convert Decimal to Two's Complement**

Convert the number to binary (ignore the sign for now) e.g. 5 is 0101 and -5 is 0101

If the number is a positive number then you are done. e.g. 5 is 0101 in binary using twos complement notation.

**Here goes your solution.**

```
If the number is negative then

3.1 find the complement (invert 0's and 1's) e.g. -5 is 0101 so finding the complement is 1010

3.2 Add 1 to the complement 1010 + 1 = 1011. Therefore, -5 in two's complement is 1011.
```

So, what if you wanted to do 2 + (-3) in binary? 2 + (-3) is -1. What would you have to do if you were using sign magnitude to add these numbers? 0010 + 1101 = ?

Using two's complement consider how easy it would be.

2  =  0010

-3 =  1101

+

---

-1 =  1111

**Converting Two's Complement to Decimal**

Converting 1111 to decimal:

The number starts with 1, so it's negative, so we find the complement of 1111, which is 0000.

Add 1 to 0000, and we obtain 0001.

Convert 0001 to decimal, which is 1.

Apply the sign = -1.

**In your case**

when you do `b.not().toString(2)` , you will get the response :

```
-11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

with **1** at the last bit.

Now do the two's compliment and you will get the right answer.

e.g; Flip all the **1's** by **0's** and vice-versa. after doing that add one to the solution and you will get the solution that you are seeking.

**Final solution**

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

VALUE = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000 - this is patern for bit 1...10...0

VALUE = 0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF - this is patern for bit 0...01...1

Just type by hand 16 x "F" and "0" and remember to add "0x"before each pattern.
Define this values as final.

If You want to generate such values you must do 
value += 0x1;
value << 1;
For n times. In your case n is 64.